# How to retrieve snapshot data using SuccessFactors Compound Employee API?

Tags: xml, api, azure-synapse, sap-successfactors

I have to retrieve employee's historical data from SuccessFactors, and I've tried to do it using SFSF Compound Employee API but it didn't work well.
I don't have experience of API call, so I didn't understand what the SFSF documentation said.

(https://help.sap.com/doc/60753cd8689244d18a6960f790b08661/2211/en-US/SF_EC_Comp_Emp_API.pdf)

In that document, the following sample code is written.

```
<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
<urn:query>
<urn:queryString>SELECT person、employment_information、job_information FROM
CompoundEmployee WHERE Person_id_external = 'admin' and snapshot_date = to_DateTime('2015-03-10T08:00:00Z')</urn:queryString>
<urn:param>
<urn:name>query mode</urn:name>
<urn:value>snapshot</urn:value>
</urn:param>
</urn:query>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I tested this with Azure synapse Analytics and it did not work.
[image: Synapse Test]
Could anyone give me the correct code or any advice?
Any answers would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

WHat is the connector you are using ? Is it REST ? I see the response as XML . At this REST connector only support JSON .

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#rest-as-source

[image]